# maven: automatic upgrade version in all dependent projects

Tags: plugins, maven, dependencies

Before the question I'd like to describe the methodology I use.
I have a lot of projects under version control folder, some of them multi maven projects, some of them standalone bundles, some of them maven plugins or archetypes. All jars are snapshot (currently we can not use release artifacts). So for example application A1 depended on bundle B, which depended on utility C, another application A2 directly depended on utility C. When I change code in C I need to update it's version and then update B and A2, then A1. It is really annoying to update all those poms once at week. So I'm looking for some automatic solution that can handle it for me (like if C has new version all depended modules have to be updated).
Does any body have idea?

Thanks in advance

P.S. I thought to make a MOJO which can handle this, but I faced with some difficulty since not all projects has common parent project ...

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like something the versions plugin can handle... http://mojohaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/

Comment: yep, specifically this mojo: http://mojo.codehaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/use-latest-releases-mojo.html

Comment: Sounds good. Thank you, I'll test it and update you with a results

Comment: http://www.mojohaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/use-latest-releases-mojo.html codehaus stopped its service, the link from @SeanPatrickFloyd does not work anymore

Comment: @wischan you're right. here's the new link: http://www.mojohaus.org//versions-maven-plugin/use-latest-releases-mojo.html

Answer (score 3):

This is considered a bad practice, but if you deploy your projects using `-DupdateReleaseInfo=true` (or with the release plugin), then you can set the dependency version to `RELEASE`

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>some.groupid</groupId>
    <artifactId>some.artifactid</artifactId>
    <version>RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

and you will always get the latest release version

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but currently we can not use release at all

Answer (score 0):

If you're using SNAPSHOT-s only, you could always go for parent based projects. Define the versions in a parent and make the children extend it. You can also choose to use versions such as RELEASE or LATEST.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a Continuous integration engine to watch all projects and build them when changed.

If you use Jenkins you can set it up to provide the built maven artifacts as a Maven repository, which you can then use in your own Maven configuration.

This should be enough - the snapshot mechanism handles the rest.